# Microsoft Video indexer can't make Japanese transcription

Tags: azure, video, azure-video-indexer

Japanese transcription can't be create by [**Video Indexer**](https://vi.microsoft.com/en-us/).

For example, using same video file and tried Japanese and English Transcription mode. (The language of the video is Japanese)

Result, English transcription could create 
, but Japanese could not create.

I tried `region == WUS2,JapanEast`. Both results were the same.

Comment: please provide more detail of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a live site in Speech services preventing Japanese transcription. We are rolling out a fix and it should get resolved. We will update you here.

Comment: Hi DashleenBhandari

thank you for your answer.
I wait for the update.

Comment: The issue has been resolved including the data centers you were using. Please verify.